# Automount CIFS shares on boot?

Tags: linux-mint, mount, cifs

I have a script saved that mounts my CIFS share, but I have to run it manually every time I boot into Linux and I connect to the internet. Is there a way that I can set the script to run as root every time Linux boots, and have it continually run until it connects to the drives? I'm running Linux Mint.

**UPDATE:** I already have the package installed. I have a working script to mount it:

```
#!/bin/sh

mount -t cifs //xxx.xxx.xxx.xx/usb1-1share1 /media/Private -o username=xx,password=xx,domain=WORKGROUP
mount -t cifs //xxx.xxx.xxx.xx/Uploads /media/Uploads -o
username=xx,password=xx,domain=WORKGROUP
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to add the entry to /etc/fstab

> //server/usb1-1share1 /media/Private cifs  username=xx,password=xx,domain=WORKGROUP
>   //server/Uploads /media/Uploads cifs username=xx,password=xx,domain=WORKGROUP

You will likely want the "noauto" mount option as well and I strongly suggest you use a credentials file instead of user name and password in /etc/fstab

Answer (score 3):

1. Install the smbfs package;
2. Create the directory for the mount (ex: `/media/lua`)
3. If you want to have the drive mounted only once use the mount command:

   ```
   $ sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.0.199/Volume_1/Pessoais /media/lua -o guest,rw,uid=1000,gid=1000,nounix,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777
   ```
4. If you want to have the drive mounted every time you boot, edit the `/etc/fstab` file:

   ```
   //192.168.0.199/Volume_1/Pessoais /media/lua cifs guest,rw,uid=1000,gid=1000,nounix,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 0 0
   ```
5. To load the fstab just type on the console:

   ```
   $ sudo mount -a
   ```

Source: [Automount CIFS shares on boot?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/103541/automount-cifs-shares-on-boot)